# code passes through $scope.options first instead of $http.get

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

i have an ion-slide component with 3 slides. when running the app the first time, all three slides load. however, going to another controller and coming back to the controller where the ion-slide is (using $state.go), only displays one slide and has the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

seeing this error, i traced it passes through this line first:

```
sharedProperties.setProperty($scope.cardNumbers[$scope.currentIdx]
.CardNumber);
```

instead of this code fetching the card number:

```
    var url = 'http://10.10.9.169/UserService3/WebService1.asmx';
    $http.get(url + '/getCardsbyUsername' + '?unameID=' + currentID ).success(function(response) {
    // stuff
        console.log('response is jsonobj = ' + response);
        var strObj = JSON.stringify(response).replace(/"(\w+)"\s*:/g, '$1:');
        var myObject = eval('(' + strObj + ')');
         $scope.cardNumbers = myObject;
         console.log('response is jsonarr = ' + $scope.cardNumbers);
    })
    .error(function(response) {
    // error stuff
        console.log('response error is = ' + response);
    });
```

here's the full code:

```
$scope.currentIdx = 0;

var currentID = sharedProperties3.getUserID();
console.log('current ID = ' + currentID);

var url = 'http://10.10.9.169/UserService3/WebService1.asmx';
    $http.get(url + '/getCardsbyUsername' + '?unameID=' + currentID ).success(function(response) {
    // stuff
        console.log('response is jsonobj = ' + response);
        var strObj = JSON.stringify(response).replace(/"(\w+)"\s*:/g, '$1:');
        var myObject = eval('(' + strObj + ')');
         $scope.cardNumbers = myObject;
         console.log('response is jsonarr = ' + $scope.cardNumbers);
    })
    .error(function(response) {
    // error stuff
        console.log('response error is = ' + response);
    });

  $scope.options1 = {
    initialSlide: 0,
    onInit: function(slider1)
    {
        $scope.slider1 = slider1;
        sharedProperties.setProperty($scope.cardNumbers[$scope.currentIdx].CardNumber);

    },
    onSlideChangeEnd: function(slider1)
    {
        console.log('The active index is ' + slider1.activeIndex); 
        $scope.currentIdx = slider1.activeIndex;
        console.log('The active card is ' + $scope.cardNumbers[$scope.currentIdx].CardNumber); 
        sharedProperties.setProperty($scope.cardNumbers[$scope.currentIdx].CardNumber);
    }
    };

  $scope.options2 = {
  direction: 'vertical',
  slidesPerView: '1',
  pagination: false,
  initialSlide: 1,
  showNavButtons: false
  };
```

how can i make it pass through the $http.get code block first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i noticed i was loading angularjs more than once, so i got rid of the extra code calling angularjs in my index.html and it worked.